# Skipping empty values in Excel worksheet

Tags: .net, excel

I have problem with reading my excel file uploaded to Blob conainer. I have method called: DownloadBlobFileToStream. It's working fine. It's creating Memory Stream to read.

The point of my problem is reading Excel Worksheet. 
With using this method:

```
using (var stream = DataAccess.DownloadBlobFileToStream(fileName, "importmatches"))
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                string text;
                var shopIds = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                int countCol = 0;
                int countRow = 0;

                foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        if(c.CellValue !=null && countRow>=1)
                        {
                            shopIds.Add(countCol, Convert.ToInt32(c.CellValue.Text));
                        }
                        countCol++;
                    }
                    countRow++;
                    countCol = 0;
                }

            }
        }
```

This way of solving problem removes empty cells. I want to skip it.
For example:
[A1] should have value: John [A2] is empty cell [A3] should have value: 2000

This implementation making it [A1] John [A2] 2000

Do you have any solutions to work with that?

Comment: So what is the real issue?  Your title implies a problem retrieving the file, but your problem statement implies an issue in manipulating the file using some variant of OpenXML.

Comment: Updated title to match content

Comment: Just want to deserialize memory Stream to Object of my class, without skipping empty cells. If I have empty cell, I want to store Null
:) Sorry for titles. Was tired after many hours of work :)